# Is there a linear dynamical system on the sphere with a two-point attractor?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, spheres

Let $N=(1,0,0)$ denote the North Pole of $\mathbb S^2$. Therefore, $-N$ denotes the South Pole.

> **Question**. Is there a skew-symmetric $M\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ such that, letting $u(t,P)\in\mathbb S^2$ denote the solution to
> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}= Mu,\qquad u(0)=P,$$
> for an arbitrary $P\in\mathbb S^2$, it holds that either $u(t,P)\to N$ or $u(t,P)\to -N$ as $t\to \infty$?

The matrix $M$ must satisfy the skew-symmetry $M^T=-M$ in order for $u(t, P)$ to remain on $\mathbb S^2$ for all $t>0$. In particular, the trace of $M$ must vanish.

---

My intuition is that such a dynamical system cannot exist. Indeed, since $\operatorname*{tr}(M)=0$, the dynamical system $u(t, \cdot)$ should be "area-preserving", in some sense. And this shouldn't be compatible with the requirement that, asymptotically, everything collapses to a couple of points, which is a set with zero area.

However, if my intuition is wrong, I would be **very** happy to see an example.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: the point of the "quote" is to provide a stand-alone question, so I restored it. Thank you for removing the {cases} environment, though. It is so much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the system explicitly to see that this isn't possible. Since $M$ is skew-symmetric, up to an orthogonal change of coordinates, it looks like

$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & -a & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

If you start with $P = \pm e_1$ then the corresponding dynamical system will just stay at $P$ (as $Me_3 = 0$). However, if you start at (say) $e_2$, the initial value problem is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} u_1'(t) \\ u_2'(t) \\ u_3'(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \\ 0 & -a & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_1(t) \\ u_2(t) \\ u_3(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ au_3(t) \\ -au_2(t) \end{pmatrix}, \,\,\,  \begin{pmatrix} u_1(0) \\ u_2(0) \\ u_3(0) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}  $$

whose solution is

$$ u_1(t) \equiv 0, u_2(t) = \cos(at), u_3(t) = -\sin(at). $$

The trajectory is a big circle on the $yz$ plane which always stays away from $\pm e_1$.

Comment: More generally, this shows that the trajectories are always obtained by rotating the sphere along an axis with uniform angular velocity $|a|$.

Comment: Right. There's not even the need for the orthogonal coordinate change you mention in the first line. The matrix $M$ must satisfy $Me_1=0$ for $e_1$ to be a fixed point. And since it must also be anti-symmetric, it must be of the form you specified.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: That's true that in the case you consider, since you want $u(t,P) \to \pm e_1$ and since a skew-symmetric matrix has a non-zero dimensional kernel, we must have $Me_1 = 0$ and then $M$ has the form written in the answer. However, even without assuming anything this is true up to an orthogonal change of coordinates.

Comment: Do you think that such a dynamical system exists in higher dimension? More precisely, is there an anti-symmetric $M\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ such that the solution to $\dot{u}=Mu$ satisfies $u(t, P)\to \pm e_1$ as $t\to \infty$, for all $P\in \mathbb S^n$? (I am considering opening another question).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: Nope. Your condition requires that $M$ should have a one-dimensional kernel $U = \operatorname{Span} \{ e_1 \}$. Since $U^{\perp}$ is $M$-invariant any trajectory which starts at $U^{\perp} \cap \mathbb{S}^n$ will stay there and won't approach $\pm e_1$.

Comment: Good observation. Thanks!