# Attractors of nonlinear dynamical systems on the sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, spheres, nonlinear-analysis

This is related to [my other recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3749756/8157), which involved linear flows on the unit sphere. Here, we are going to consider nonlinear flows.

---

Let $\mathbb S^{d-1}=\{x\in\mathbb R^d\ :\ x^Tx=1\}$ denote the unit sphere. Let moreover $A$ be a real $d\times d$ matrix.

[Following this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282583/13042) we consider the unique solution $x(t, x_0)$ to the nonlinear initial value problem
$$
\dot{x}=(I-x x^T)Ax, \quad x(0)=x_0\in \mathbb S^{d-1}. $$
For $x\in \mathbb S^{d-1}$, that is $\lvert x \rvert^2=1$, we see that
$$\tfrac{d}{dt}(x^T x)=x^TA^Tx-x^TA^Tx\lvert x\rvert^2+x^TAx - \lvert x \rvert^2 x^TAx=0,$$
so $x(t, x_0)$ remains on $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ for all $t>0$.

Now the linked MathOverflow question states, without proof, that if $A$ is negative semi-definite, then

> $x(t, x_0)$ converges to a stable equilibrium.

**Can you prove an appropriate version of this statement?**

---

Here's some of my thoughts.

I can think of two versions of the statement to prove. But I cannot prove either of them. First of all, it is easy to see that the normalized eigenvectors of $A$ correspond to equilibria; precisely, if $Av=\lambda v$ and $v\in \mathbb S^{d-1}$ then
$$
\left.\tfrac{d}{dt} x(t, v)\right|_{t=0}= (I-vv^T)\lambda v=0,$$
which implies that $x(t, v)=v$ for all $t\ge 0$. This leads me to think that the "stable equilibrium" mentioned in the statement above is an eigenvector. The two conjectures follow.

**Conjecture 1**. For each $x_0\in \mathbb S^{d-1}$ there is an eigenvector $v\in\mathbb S^{d-1}$ of $A$ such that $x(t, x_0)\to v$ as $t\to \infty$.

**Conjecture 2**. (stronger). Let $\lambda_j$ denote the eigenvalues of $A$ and suppose that $0>\lambda_1>\lambda_j$ for all $j>1$, and that $\lambda_1$ is non-degenerate. Let $v\in \mathbb S^{d-1}$ be a $\lambda_1$-eigenvector of $A$. Then
$$
x(t, x_0)\to v,\quad \text{or}\quad x(t, x_0)\to -v$$
as $t\to \infty$, unless $v^Tx_0=0$. (In the latter case the system never leaves the $(d-2)$ dimensional sphere $\{x\in\mathbb R^d\ :\ v^Tx=0,\ \lvert x\rvert^2=1\}$).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I followed your advice and used the "quote" environment for an actual quote of another question, instead of highlighting some text. I think you are right, it is nicer this way. Thank you

Comment: I'll just write few observations that I've made fiddling with this problem. First of all we can change coordinates in such way that equations become very simple. Since in the original problem $A$ is symmetric matrix, we can look for an orthogonal change of coordinates $x = Sy, \; S S^T = I$. After these changes we get equations $\dot{y} = (I- y y^T)\, Jy$, where $J$ is a Jordan normal form of $A$. Since symmetric matrices are diagonalisable, the equations can be rewritten simply as $$\dot{y}_i = y_i \left ( \lambda_i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\, y^2_j \right ). $$

Comment: We can always reorder coordinates in such way that $y_1 = 1, y_i = 0$ corresponds to the leading (i.e., closest to zero) eigenvalue. I think I have to correct your hypothesis there: the normalized eigenvectors, corresponding to the leading (not largest) eigenvalue, should be stable equilibria on the sphere. I've used SymPy to check Jacobi matrix of this system when $n = 3$ at $(1, 0, 0)$ : I got matrix ${\rm diag}\, (-2\lambda_1, \lambda_2 - \lambda_1, \lambda_3 - \lambda_1)$. While this equlibrium is unstable in the whole phase space (since $-2\lambda_1 > 0$), it can be stable ...

Comment: ... iff $\lambda_2 < \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_3 < \lambda_1$ when we restrict system to sphere $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i^2 = 1$ . I'm currently checking the following idea: if we'd show that $y^2_1 \rightarrow 1$ as $t \rightarrow +\infty$ while we are on sphere, it would probably mean that we are converging either to $(-1, 0, \dots, 0)$ or $(1, 0, \dots , 0)$ provided that we haven't started on $(0, 0, \dots , 0)$. A good candidate for this is just to check that $\frac{d}{dt}(y^2_1) = y_1^2 (\lambda_1 - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j^2) > 0$ while trajectory stays on sphere.

Comment: You are welcome! I think that it is possible to show that $\frac{d}{dt}(y_1^2) > 0$ using [Rayleigh's quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient). Then we have that $y^2_1(t)$ is strictly increasing along the solution. It feels that [Barbalat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Barbalat's_lemma_and_stability_of_time-varying_systems) can be applied to $1-y^2_1$: this lemma would imply that as $1-y^2_1$ decreases to some limit, its derivative $(1-y^2_1)' = -2 y_1 \dot{y}_1$ goes to zero. Since $y_1$ is non-zero, we have that $y^2_1 (t) \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @Evgeny: I am sorry to come back after a long while, but I have been distracted from this question. I don't understand what you mean with the last comment; how to use the "Rayleigh quotient"?

Comment: No problem :) The expression $\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j^2$ is equivalent to $\frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j^2}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n y_j^2}$ when we are considering it on unit sphere. As it is stated on Wikipedia, $\lambda_{\rm min} \leqslant \frac{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j^2}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n y_j^2} \leqslant \lambda_{\rm max} = \lambda_1$ (remember that all our eigenvalues are negative and we reordered them in a way that $\lambda_1$ is closest to zero). From this follows that $\lambda_1 - \sum\limits_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j^2 \geqslant 0$.

Comment: @Evgeny: I agree that your program works. I have carried it out and I wrote an answer. Actually, as H.H.Rugh points out, it is not necessary that $A$ is definite negative. It suffices that it is symmetric with a non-degenerate largest eigenvalue, the same proof you suggested will work in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a remark: It seems rather odd to ask for $A$ to be negative definite, since the sphere becomes repelling and the problem is unstable when running forward in time! One has:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} (1-x^t x)^2 = - 2 (1-x^tx)^2 (x^t A x).$$
So for $x\neq 0$, $|1-x^tx|$ is decreasing when $A$ is positive definite  and the equation is globally stable only in that case.

Suppose $v\in {\Bbb R}^d\setminus\{0\}$ is a fixed point. Then you find $Av=\lambda v$ and $v^t v=1$.
Linearizing  around the fixed point, $x=v+z$ ($z$ small), yields:
$$ \dot{z}= (A-\lambda) z - 2 \lambda v (v^t z)+o(z)= (A-\lambda-2\lambda vv^t) z + o(z).$$
In the $v$-direction you need $\lambda>0$ for global stability as already mentioned. In an orthogonal direction, $v^tz=0$, i.e. tangent to the sphere, we have $\dot{z}=(A-\lambda)z$ which gives stability precisely when $\lambda$ is a largest isolated eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something from your analysis. You convinced me that the definite negative assumption is unnatural and I will drop it. I still think that it is important that $A$ is symmetric, though. In that case, it can be orthogonally diagonalized, the system reduces to $$\dot{x}_i=x_i(\lambda_i-\sum\lambda_jx_j^2), $$
and this can be used to establish that the leading non-degenerate eigenvector is globally attractive (essentially because the squares $x_i^2$ satisfy an ODE, as I write in my answer). On the other hand, your nice analysis only works locally, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro You are welcome. The best is probably to assume that $A$ is positive definite or close to such (in principle it need not be symmetric but then the stability analysis becomes harder). The leading eigenvalue is not really globally attractive since the other eigenvectors remain fixed points. But is it the only stable fixed point, as also follows from your analysis (modulo the problem with positive/negative definiteness). Cheers!

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I stayed with the assumption that $A$ is negative-definite since it was mentioned in the original post on MO. I agree that inner dynamics on the sphere really doesn't need $A$ being negative-definite and I was pretty okay with sphere being repelling since the question asked only about dynamics on the sphere :) (Also saddle invariant sets are all around me :D) I still wonder what technique could be used to the case of non-symmetric $A$. The local stability doesn't require diagonalization as was shown by you, but the stability of leading eigenvector in the whole hemisphere puzzles me.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  From a theoretical point of view any $A$ will give rise to a flow on the sphere. But if you want to run it on a computer, it is better  if $A+A^t$ is positive definite  (this suffices in view of my first equation) in order for the  numerical trajectory to stay on the sphere. I think it is an error in the original MO post.  As you say  there are a lot of saddle points and the flow looks a bit like a Morse-Smale gradient flow.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the substantial input given by Evgeny in comments. Thank you Evgeny!

---

Since $A$ is definite negative, up to an orthogonal change of coordinates we can rewrite the system
$$\tag{1}\dot{x}=(I-xx^T)Ax, \quad x\in\mathbb R^n,$$
as
$$\tag{2}
\dot{x}_i=x_i(-\lambda_i +\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j x_j^2),\quad i=1, \ldots, n,$$
where
$$0<\lambda_1< \lambda_2\le \lambda_3\ldots$$
and
$$
Ae_j=-\lambda_j e_j, \qquad \text{ where }e_i=(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0).$$
(Searching the literature, I see that $\lambda_1$ is often called *spectral gap*, and $-\lambda_1$ is the  *leading eigenvalue*).

**Assumption**. I am assuming that $\lambda_1$ is simple, meaning that the only normalized eigenvectors corresponding to $-\lambda_1$ are $\pm e_1$.

**Side remark**. The eigenvectors $e_i$ are equilibria of (1). The change of variable $x=y+e_i$ produces the equivalent system
$$\tag{3}
\dot{y}=(A+\lambda_i I + 2\lambda_i e_i e_i^T)y+ 2\lambda_iy_i y - y^TAy e_i -y^TAy y.$$
The matrix in round brackets is the linearization of (1) around the equilibrium point $e_i$. However, this does not seem to play a role in the present analysis.

---

**CLAIM** . For each $x_0\in\mathbb S^{n-1}$, either

$$\lvert x(t)-e_1\rvert \to 0, \quad \text{or} \quad \lvert x(t)+e_1\rvert\to 0,$$ or $e_1^Tx(t)=0$ for all times. (In this latter case, (1) reduces to an ODE on $\mathbb S^{n-2}$, and if $\lambda_2$ is simple, this claim applies to it).

*Proof*. Letting $y_i=x_i^2$ we see that these functions satisfy a differential system;
$$\tag{4}
\frac{d y_i}{dt}=2y_i(-\lambda_i + \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j), \qquad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Also, obviously, $y_i\in[0,1]$ and $\sum y_i=1$.

Now, $\sum \lambda_j y_j\ge \lambda_1 y_1$, with strict inequality unless $y_1=1, y_2=0, \ldots, y_n=0$. So we see that $\dot{y}_1>0$, unless $y_1=0$ or $y_1=1$. In the first case, we have $e_1^Tx(t)=0$ for all times. In the latter case, we have $x(t)=e_1$ or $x(t)=-e_1$ for all times.

It remains to consider the case $y_1\in (0, 1)$ and $\dot{y}_1>0$. Since $y_1$ is strictly increasing, it has a limit as $t\to \infty$, and by uniform continuity it must be $\dot{y}_1(t)\to 0$. Thus, (4) shows that $(-\lambda_i + \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j y_j)$ must vanish as $t\to \infty$, and this can only happen if $y_1^2\to 1$. This concludes the proof. $\Box$

**Side remark**. The system (4) can be written in matrix form by letting $\mathbf 1^T=(1, 1,\ldots, 1)$;
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=(2I -2y \mathbf 1^T)Ay.$$